# CGContextStrokePath color

Tags: ios

I use CGContextStrokePath painted on a straight line in a white background picture, stroke color is red, alpha is 1.0
After drawing the line, why the points is not (255, 0, 0), but (255, 96, 96)
Why not pure red?

Comment: What are the coordinates of your line's endpoints?

Comment: You're using [UIColor red]? How are you determining the results? (What sort of device?) I suspect some sort of colorspace issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quartz (the iOS drawing layer) uses antialiasing to make things look smooth.  That's why you're seeing non-pure-red pixels.

If you stroke a line of width 1.0 and you want only pure red pixels, the line needs to be horizontal or vertical and it needs to run along the center of the pixels, like this:

```
CGContextMoveToPoint(gc, 0, 10.5);
CGContextAddLineToPoint(gc, 50, 10.5);
CGContextStroke(gc);
```

The .5 in the y coordinates puts the long along the centers of the pixels.

Comment: This is it. Cocoa's coordinates are for the middle of the line, not the outside or inside edge of the line the way other api's do it (eg:HTML/ CSS). With a low resolution output such as a typical Mac LCD that will often draw the line two half pixels wide.